# Excel 2016 chart to compare growth with 4 parameters

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In my Excel 2016 worksheet, I have a great amount of data (~224 000 lines / 5 columns) with this format :

```
Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3 | Parameter 4 | Result     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 0          |
1           | 0           | 0           | 0           | 1          |
0           | 1           | 0           | 0           | 2          |
0           | 0           | 1           | 0           | 3          |
0           | 0           | 0           | 1           | 4          |
1           | 1           | 0           | 0           | 5          |
[...]
```

The format is comparable to a "binary" word where every value is tested in each column, each amounting to a different result in the "Result" column.

Is there any way to create a chart (either curve or scatter plots) that would make it possible to see which of the 4 parameter make the "Result" grow faster?

I tried selecting my 5 columns to create a graph, but the result is a "dented" curve. Even when using only one parameter at a time with the "result", gave me a dented curve, since the data is the "parameter x" column, goes from 0 to n and resets multiple times over the 200k+ lines.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of what I get with XY Graph :

[image: XY Graph]

The Y-axis is the value in "Result", the X-axis is the line number.

The Result column is yellow in this graph.

**EDIT 2**

The Result is analog to this formula :

```
Result = (Constant + Parameter 1) * (1 + Parameter 2 / 100) * (1 + Parameter 3 / 100 * Parameter 4 / 100)
```

Comment: My suggestion is, if the listed Data Set is genuine then either you created Clustered Bar Graph or XY Graph.

Comment: @RajeshS The Data Set is not real, the first parameter goes from 0 to 61 increment 1, the second from 0 to 40 increment 10, the third from 0 to 100 increment 1 and the fourth 25 to 40 increment 5.

Comment: This is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_approximation problem and is rather a job for a math package.

Comment: How do you calculate the Result from the four parameters? Is it a weighted sum of each parameter, as if it were binary? If it was binary, the weights would be 8,4,2,1.  What are they actually?

Comment: And you need to explain the graph.  I can only see 4 data series.  Which color series represents which parameter and which is the result?

Comment: @Bandersnatch I added some info in my post.

Comment: I agree with ivan_pozdeev, this question is not really related to Excel, as you are not asking how to make a specific chart, but what chart type fits your data. You might get better answer on a math / statistical site. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @Máté, this question might be answerable by using analysis tools available in Excel. I'll give it a try if I can understand the data.

Comment: @Bandersnatch: you pointed out correctly: " if I can understand the data", the key here is not how to do the chart, but what to do, and that has to be defined independently from Excel.

Comment: Well, I could **describe** what to do, but I want to test it first. And that means I need the data.  His formula might do the trick, I'll let you know in a bit.

Comment: Serenity, I think the series in your graph with gray symbols is the fourth parameter, which you describe as going from "25 to 40, increment 5". But it only increments every 55k "line numbers", unlike the other parameters. Could you please **clearly** explain: 1) what the x-axis in your graph is, 2) how and when P4 increments, 3) how it takes P3 55K "line numbers" to get to 100 if it is incrementing by 1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary Stuff** (skip this if you want to cut to the chase):

Serenity, I have tried to reproduce your graph to check that I have understood your problem correctly, and I was able to "get close".  There are two major differences:

1. Your graph shows the Result and Parameter 3 "resetting" at an
   x-value of around 55,000.  Yet you say that Parameter 3 goes from 0
   to 100 (incrementing by 1) and then repeats. You also say that
   the x-axis is the line number.  These statements are contradictory,
   unless the line number is something very different from an integer
   series (i.e. the row number) in Excel.
2. Your graph **does not** show Parameter 1, which you say goes from 0
   to 61 with an increment of 1 and then repeats.  But your graph
   **does** show a series (gray symbols) that starts at around 30 and increases in jumps throughout the range shown.

So, the following analysis will show you in general how to proceed, but the conclusion applies to the data I have generated from your comments, and not to the data shown in your graph.

**Important Stuff** (start here if you want to cut to the chase):

In the graphs below, I have plotted the Result, and four more series produced by **removing** one of the four parameters from the calculation.  These are labeled P123, P124, P134, and P234 - they were generated by removing Parameters 4,3,2 and 1, respectively.

For Parameters 2,3 and 4, I removed the entire term (i.e (1+Param2/100) from your equation.  For Parameter 1, which is multiplied by a constant, I removed **just** Parameter 1.  You may decide to handle this differently.  Also note that I used a value of 300 for the constant, because that gives an initial value for Result of 75, which is about what your graph shows.

The graph below shows Result and the four Pnnn series, with a linear trendline fitted to each series. This graph is a bit messy, but one thing is clear: removing Parameter 4 **increases** the slope of the trendline. i.e. P123 "grows" faster than Result, so that means Parameter 4 has a **negative** contribution to the growth of Result - it decreases it.

[image]

The next graph expands the lower portion of the first graph, and includes the equations for the linear fits. (P123 is off scale, but the uppermost equation is for its trendline).

The slope of the trendline for Result is 0.0584.  The slopes for P234, P134 and P124 are all lower, which means the missing Parameters each have a positive effect on growth - adding them back would increase the slope to  0.0584.  The lowest slope is for P124. This means that **Parameter 3 has the biggest effect on the growth of Result**.

As I said above, you may find a different result if you apply this kind of analysis to the data you have.

But I hope this helps, and good luck.

[image]

NOTE: To add a trendline to a series (in Excel 2011 for Mac), click on one of the points in the series, and choose "Add Trendline..." from the Graph menu. In the resulting dialog box, under Type, choose Linear fit, and under "Options", select the checkbox for "Display equation on chart".  The details of this may vary depending on your version of Excel.

EDIT: I want to point out that the "growth" of this function is a bit misleading.  Because all four of the parameters are cyclic functions, in the long run, the slope of all of them is zero.  Result "grows" only for the initial cycles of the parameter with the longest period (P3).  But, at large enough values of x, Result will level off, and the slope of a linear fit will approach zero.  To demonstrate this, you can do a linear fit to n cycles of P3, and see the slope decrease as n increases.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your analysis. This is extremely useful. Removing 1 parameter to compare the graphs is really clever. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Glad to help.